# How can I calculate directly test estimated error in confusion matrix?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(123)
library(boot)
glm.fit=glm(Species~.,data=iris)
cv.error= cv.glm(iris, glm.fit,K=10)$delta[1]
cv.error #MSE for each model
```

But I wish to get using table from confusion matrix.

```
set.seed(7)
x = iris[,-5]
y = iris$Species
model = train(x,y,"nb",trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10))
confusionMatrix(model)
```

Question:

1. Is the estimated error rate using 1- output of average accuracy?
2. Any method to extract?
3. I wish to get in integer figure ie.

```
          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 122 11
         1 98 320
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the confusion matrix as e.g. object you can try

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
model <- train(Species~., data=iris,
               method="nb",
               trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=5))

qq<-confusionMatrix(model)
```

If you prefer to have the "full numbers" rather than percentages you will have to look at how many datapoints you originally had - here you have 150.
All you have to do now is take the table, divide it by 100 and multiply everything with 150 - done

```
final_result<-qq$table/100*150
```